# Mediaelement js playlist change

Tags: javascript, web, mediaelement.js, mediaelement, playlist

I build a webpage, which must able to change playlist via a single button.
My site already contains the following JS libraries:

- mediaelement.js
  mediaelement.js playlist plugin
- angular.js
  ui-router

The mediaelement js and the corresponding playlist plugin code is:

```
    <script>$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
        loop: true,
        shuffle: true,
        playlist: false,
        audioHeight: 30,
        playlistposition: 'bottom',
        features: ['playlistfeature', 'prevtrack', 'playpause', 'nexttrack', 'loop', 'shuffle', 'playlist', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume'],
        keyActions: []
      });</script>
    <div id="mediawrapper">
    <audio id="mejs" class="mep-playlist mep-slider" width="100%" height="100"
      data-showplaylist="true" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
      <Source src="music/The_Tokens.mp3" title="The Tokens - Lions Sleeps Tonight"></Source>
      <Source src="music/Vili zenél.m4a" title="Vili zenél."></Source>
    </audio>
    </div>
```

It works fine, but I cannot reach the Source tag with JQuery (because the plugin builds the playlist from that). I want to add a button which changes the standard playlist to another. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try using the `setSrc()` within the callback of your button `click` event